# No gradients provided when training word embeddings from dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to train a custom word embedding from a TF2 dataset. My text is already encoded as integers, and my model works fine on example datasets (i.e. those loaded from the [tfds catalog](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/overview#text)). But when I put in my tensors from my (batched) dataset, the model fails to begin training with `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['embed/embeddings:0', 'relu/kernel:0', 'relu/bias:0', 'out/kernel:0', 'out/bias:0'].`

Confused on why this is happening. An example of similar code which causes the same error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras import layers

# build example dataset
tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)

model = keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(100, 18, name='embed'),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', name='relu'),
  layers.Dense(1, name='out')
], name="embedder")

model.summary() # shows 2,121 trainable params
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit( # breaks here
    dataset,
    epochs=10,
    validation_data=dataset)
```

Comment: can you provide the code that does work

Comment: No, I'm trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `x` parameter for `tf.keras.Sequential.fit` says ([original documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential?hl=en#fit), I'm bolding the section that seems relevant since a dataset is being used):

> Input data. It could be:
>
> - A Numpy array (or array-like), or a list of arrays (in case the model has multiple inputs).
> - A TensorFlow tensor, or a list of tensors (in case the model has multiple inputs).
> - A `dict` mapping input names to the corresponding array/tensors, if the model has named inputs.
> - A `tf.data dataset`. **Should return a tuple of either (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights).**
> - A generator or `keras.utils.Sequence` returning (inputs, targets) or (inputs, targets, sample_weights). A more detailed description of unpacking behavior for iterator types (Dataset, generator, Sequence) is given below.

However, it looks like the dataset has been set up to yield only single tensors (not tuples of tensors):

```py
tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tensor)
print(dataset.element_spec)
>>> TensorSpec(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.int32, name=None)
```

Constructing the dataset with a list of `targets` should provide the model with what it needs:

```
tensor = tf.constant([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
  tensor,
  [[0.0], [1.0], [1.0]]  # Arbitrary targets.
))
print(dataset.element_spec)
>>> (TensorSpec(shape=(3, 1), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32, name=None))
```